# How to have tooltip follow cursor when hovering on bar

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

[Here's my code in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-3dy7t)

**The code in sandbox is fully working,(component based) but when i transfer it in actual it's not working**

Comment: Textual information is preferred as text directly here, a link to a runnable demo is appreciated but only additionally. Also your last edit removed the non-code text you provided, which is important. That is why I undid your last edit.

Answer (score 0):

would be best if you share a working example of your code in a Sandbox/JSBin or similar. Then it is easier to help.

But one thing:
in v4 of d3

> d3.mouse(container)
>
> Returns the x and y coordinates of the current event relative to the
> specified **container**.

What you want is `d3.event.pageX` which gives you:

> An integer value, in pixels, indicating the X coordinate at which the mouse pointer was located when the event occurred. This value is relative to the left edge of the entire document, regardless of the current horizontal scrolling offset of the document.

But to be certain I would need to see a working example to try this out.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-3dy7t   please help me thanks @mila_frerichs

Comment: can you explain what is not working? you said it's working in the sandbox and I can see that, but what is not working in your project?

Comment: my appologies, the problem is unknown, when we append the code in modal  as same approach in sandbox it's not working. will it work the same if it was put in a modal?

Comment: not sure I follow. what do you mean with modal? an overlay over the page?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/2781d0dfe94854c9f3bf784705ecc166.png here's the actual picture of my project @mila_frerichs

Comment: our situation here is once the user clicks the (DIV)container it will expand with detailed barChart with hover effect on it, but it didnt work :(

Comment: I see, so in this case you probably looking at a few things depending on how you implemented it. 1) look at the z-index of the tooltip div, it should be higher than the overlay z-index. you could inspect your code and see if the tooltip div left and top changes when you hover over your graph. this is an indication that the z-index is to blame 2) if it's an iframe, the tooltip needs to be in that iframe as well.

Answer (score 0):

For D3 v4 specifically:

Append a div using d3:

```
const tooltip = d3
      .select('body')
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'tooltip');
```

Now Add a mousemove and mouseout listener:

```
  d3.on('mousemove', () => {
    return tooltip
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 30 + 'px')
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 'px');
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(this.transitionDuration * 0.2)
      .style('fill', `green`);
    return tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
```